# Teradata CONCAT seems to create extra spaces

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following code and output

```
select
case
when min_value = 2500000 then CONCAT('>$', min_value)
when max_value= 0 then  CONCAT('<$', max_value)
when max_value= 749999 then CONCAT('$',min_value, ' - ', '$', max_value + 1)
when max_value= 1499999 then CONCAT('$',min_value, ' - ', '$', max_value + 1)
when max_value= 2499999 then CONCAT('$',min_value, ' - ', '$', max_value + 1)
end as range_,
from mytable
```

[image: output]

As you can see in the output, there is a bunch of extra spaces that shouldn't be there. While this is functional, it isn't pretty. For background, min_value and max_value are both NUMBER(10,0) columns in this table.

When I try adding TRIM( before CONCAT, it doesn't do anything as well.

Anyone with insight and help in this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the data type of `max_value` and `min_value`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff both NUMBER(10,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who come across this in the future, here is the fix. Basically, you have to trim EACH part (because there are spaces coming from each part). It should look like this:

```
CONCAT('$',TRIM(min_value), ' - ', '$', TRIM(max_value + 1))
```

Applying TRIM before CONCAT won't do anything for you. They need to be with the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit cast is adding white space to match the size of the number field.  You can either trim it (it's working for me), or explicitly cast the number to varchar.  I'd go with explicitly casting it, not a big fan of implicit casting.

```
select 
'a' || trim(cast(1 as number(10))),
'a' || cast(cast(1  as number(10)) as varchar(10))
```

Both of those return `a1` for me.